# Update old SQL WHERE clause builder to Spring Data solution?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, querydsl

Consider the following example of an old SQL query in Java:

(I had to sanitize this, so it may not actually compile.)

```
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
ResultSet result = null;
String whereClause = null;
whereClause = getWhereClause(clientSearch);
List l = new ArrayList();
int nextParam = 1;
boolean isPreClient = false;
String sql = "SELECT c." + CL_CLIENT_USER_ID + ",u." + US_FIRST_NM +
    ",u." + US_LAST_NM + ",u." + US_SSN + ",c." + CL_APP_SITE_CD +
    ",c." + CL_SYS_USER_ID + ",c." + CL_APP_USER_TYP_CD +
    ",c." + CL_PREREG_CMPL_CD +
    ",c." + CL_SPC_CAT_CD +
    ",c." + CL_REENLISTED_CD +
    ",u." + US_EMAIL_ADDR_TX +
    ",c." + CL_SPECIAL_PROGRAM_CD +
    " FROM " + DBT_APP_USERS + " u," + DBT_APP_CLIENT + " c " +
    whereClause +
    " ORDER BY " + US_LAST_NM + "," + US_FIRST_NM;


try {
    con = DbHelper.getConnection();
    stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    if (clientSearch.isActive()) {
    stmt.setInt(nextParam, ConstantsDB.ACTIVE);
    nextParam++;
    stmt.setInt(nextParam, ConstantsDB.MODIFIED);
    nextParam++;
    } else {
    stmt.setInt(nextParam, ConstantsDB.INACTIVE);
    nextParam++;
    }
...

result = stmt.executeQuery();
    while (result.next()) {
    isPreClient = getIsPreClient(result.getInt(1), result);
    l.add(new ClientListVO(result.getInt(1), forJava(result.getString(2)),
        forJava(result.getString(3)), forJava(result.getString(4)), result.getInt(5),
        result.getInt(6), result.getInt(7), result.getDate(8),
        result.getDate(9), forJava(result.getString(10)), result.getDate(11), null,
        result.getInt(12));
    }
...

private String getWhereClause(ClientSearchVO clientSearch) {
    String whereClause;

    if (clientSearch.isActive()) {
        whereClause = " WHERE u." + US_SYS_USER_ID + "=c." + CL_SYS_USER_ID
                + " AND c." + CL_ELMT_STATUS_CD + " IN (?,?)";
    } else {
        whereClause = " WHERE u." + US_SYS_USER_ID + "=c." + CL_SYS_USER_ID
                + " AND c." + CL_ELMT_STATUS_CD + "=?";
    }

    if (clientSearch.getSsnFull() != null) {
        whereClause = whereClause + " AND u." + US_SSN + "=?";
    }
    if (clientSearch.isSearchPrereg()) {
        whereClause = whereClause
                + " AND LENGTH(U." + US_SSN + ")=?";
    }

    if (clientSearch.getSsnLastFour() != null) {
        whereClause = whereClause + " AND (substr(u." + US_SSN + ",6,4)=? OR u."
                + US_SSN + "=?)";
    }
    if (clientSearch.getLastName() != null) {
        whereClause = whereClause + " AND UPPER(u." + US_LAST_NM + ") like ?";
    }

    if (clientSearch.getClientId() > 0) {
        whereClause = whereClause + " AND c." + CL_CLIENT_USER_ID + "=?";
    }
    return whereClause;
}
```

I need to convert this kind of code for a newer application. I'm using BOM version 1.5x of Spring Data JPA, Spring Boot, etc. I can't upgrade to Spring Boot 2, because I don't currently have access to the newer Servlet versions.

The above code is for a search screen that is searching and pulling data from database tables APP_CLIENT and APP_USERS. I'm not sure what to do with it, due to the WHERE clause being built as such.

I was thinking about doing something like this:

```
public class ClientSearchResult {
    protected AppClient client;
    protected AppUsers user;

    public ClientSearchResult(AppClient client, AppUsers user) {
        this.client = client;
        this.user = user;
    }

    ...deligate methods
}

public interface AppClientRepo extends JpaRepository<AppClient, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT new ClientSearchResult(au, ac) FROM AppUsers au, AppClient ac "
            + "WHERE  "
            + "ORDER BY au.lastNm, au.firstNm ")
    List<ClientSearchResult> findBySearchCriteria(@Param("someParam01") long someParam01, @Param("someParam02") String someParam02);

}
```

I'm not sure what to do about the WHERE clause, however. If someone knows a good way to convert such code into a more modern approach, I would love to hear about it. A simple method would be preferred, but not required.

Comment: Does your solution have to be Spring Data based only or is a third party library, such as jooq.org an option? I'm asking because 1) You seem to be using some dynamic SQL, which is one of jOOQ's strengths and 2) Both Spring Boot Spring Data JDBC encourage third party library usage, see e.g. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-jooq